# Error connecting to ftp: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: sftp, vsftpd

I'm trying to connect to the server running vsftpd:

```
$ sudo systemctl status vsftpd
● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-11-24 10:48:47 UTC; 2s ago
    Process: 6135 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 6136 (vsftpd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 21449)
     Memory: 804.0K
        CPU: 4ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/vsftpd.service
             └─6136 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

my current config `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`  is as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/vsftpd.conf
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
force_dot_files=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
utf8_filesystem=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
#rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
#rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.

#############################################
#Uncomment these lines to enable FXP support#
#############################################
#pasv_promiscuous=YES
#port_promiscuous=YES

###################
#Set a custom port#
###################
#listen_port=
```

when I connect `sudo curlftpfs ubuntu@seed.myvps.xyz /path/to/dir`
I get the error message: `Error connecting to ftp: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Is there a base working conf file I could use?

Comment: Note that your systemctl output shows `/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf` and you mentioning a *current  config `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`*  ; unless the two are symlinked that may explain difficulties; additionally first test if regular FTP works as expected before complicating your setup with [`CurlFtpFS`](https://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) (if you should be using that anyway: it seems like an abandoned opensource project anyway)

Comment: thanks! i forgot to open the firewall port. that's the issue...

Answer (score 0):

sorry opened the wrong port in the firewall!!